# Why does an If statement behave differently for range compared to just a cell in excel

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

Say I want to output a column that ignores "-" and "" cells and returns anything else.

`=IF(OR(A2="",A2="-"),"",A2)` and dragging down works but why cant this be applied to a range of values?

For example:

`=IF(OR(A2:A11="",A2:A11="-"),"",A2:A11)` just returns blank cells.

Similarly:
`=IF(OR((A2:A11="")*(A2:A11=""),(A2:A11="-")*(A2:A11="-")),"",A2:A11)` causes the same result.

Could anyone explain why this happens.

Thanks

Comment: What do you think `A2:A11=""` means?  Why do you think Excel agrees with you?

Comment: @Scott Hunter Based on other equations that appear work in a similar way,my current  understating is that that its saying for each cell within range A2:A11 check if blank and then do whatever the if statement says if true or false. For example I have an equation =IF(A1:A50=""),"",A1:A50) And this works to prevent blank cells from returning as 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or accepts arrays and returns a single value

so you can do:

```
=OR(A2:A11="",A2:A11="-")
```

and it will return either a single TRUE if any in the range are `""` or FALSE if none are blank.  It will not return an array of TRUE/FALSE like an array formula needs.

[image]

So we must do:

```
=(A2:A11="")+(A2:A11="-")
```

Which will return an array of numbers. In this case either `0` or `1`.  So this array will be a 1 dimension array of 10 numbers.

[image]

Then when included in the if it compares arrays to arrays.

That is why array formula, including the new dynamic array formula FILTER will not work with `OR` or `AND` and must use `+` or `*` respectively.

So in your instance it needs to be:

```
=IF((A2:A11="")+(A2:A11="-"),"",A2:A11)
```

[image]